# How to combine 2 COPY in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to combine 2 COPY in one line with other source and destinations.

My current code:

```
COPY ./file1.txt /first/path/
COPY ./file2.txt /second/path/
```

I want combine these lines in one line. I tried with an array, but it's not correct:

```
COPY ["./file1.txt", "/first/path/", "./file2.txt", "/second/path/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a multi-line COPY statement and specify multiple src and dest pairs:

like this
COPY
./file1.txt /first/path/
./file2.txt /second/path/

This will copy file1.txt to /first/path/ and file2.txt to /second/path/.

or

COPY --from=0 ./file1.txt /first/path/ --from=0 ./file2.txt /second/path/

This will also copy file1.txt to /first/path/ and file2.txt to /second/path/.

Answer (score 0):

The COPY and ADD steps can have multiple source arguments, but only a single destination. When that syntax is used, the following requirement applies:

> If multiple `<src>` resources are specified, either directly or due to the use of a wildcard, then `<dest>` must be a directory, and it must end with a slash `/`.

For more details, see the Dockerfile documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy